# Error loading js/css ressource when nginx reverse proxy (SWAG) used

Tags: proxy, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, wireguard

I'm currently trying to setup a reverse proxy on my own server, but I have a problem. For an app in particular (here wg-easy), the web page doesn't work because all the ressources except the HTML main page code cannot load correctly. When inspecting the code from my .js and .css ressource, I can see that the main page HTML code replaced the js/css code. I'm pretty sure this comes from the reverse proxy but cannot find out more.

Here you can see my reverse-proxy conf file:
[image: reverse-proxy conf]
Someone told me it was a Content-Type error, So i try adding the header you can see, but nothing change, same result with or without. I also try to take inspiration of already provided template by SWAG but didn't manage to fix it.
Here the js ressource on my site:
[image: js file error]
And it works perfectly without using the reverse-proxy.

Thanks in advance for your help! :)